# Is the following code right recursive code?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int Largest(int arr[], int start, int end,int max) {

if (end > 0)
{
    if (arr[end] > arr[end - 1])
    {
        if (arr[end - 1] > max)
        {
            max = arr[end];
            Largest(arr,start,end-1,max);
        }
        else
            Largest(arr,start,end-1,max);
    }
    else
    {
        if (arr[end - 1] > max)
        {
            max = arr[end-1];
            Largest(arr,start,end-1,max);
        }
        else
            Largest(arr,start,end-1,max);
    }
}
else
    return max;
}

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {700,999,199,200,699};
    int start = 0, end = 4, max = 0;
    int maximum = Largest(arr,start,end,max);
    cout << endl << endl << "Maximum = " << maximum << endl << endl;
}
```

I have to write a recursive c++ code to find largest number from array. I have written this code and its working fine. But, as I am new to recursion I do not know this code is right. I am in doubt because I have called the function many times. So, please tell me is this right recursive code  ?

Comment: You don't do anything with the return values from the recursive calls, so probably it is not correct.

Comment: @NeilButterworth What do you mean  ? Please elxplain?

Comment: There is no return in your if case ..else return max because of that Control may reach end of non-void function

Comment: @Student28 You need to return the results of the recursive calls.

Comment: See my answer below. May be it will help you and only one recursive call.

Comment: @Charu  I just want to ask something. If I use return in my code with function of Largest (where I am calling Largest), will this make my code recursive code ?

Comment: @HariomSingh I just want to ask something. If I use return in my code with function of Largest (where I am calling Largest), will this make my code recursive code ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I just want to ask something. If I use return in my code with function of Largest (where I am calling Largest), will this make my code recursive code ?

Comment: @Student28 A recursive function is any function that may call itself at some point. The function you posted already *is* recursive; it just doesn't work.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Can I use recursive call more than one time. And what is the proper way of making recursive call ? Can you please tell me in one statement ?

Comment: @Student28 That's way to broad of a l question answer in the comments. Can you be more specific about what you're asking? A proper recursive call would just be a recursive call that does what you want.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Just tell me Can I use recursive call more than one time.

Comment: @Student28 Yes, you can recurse more than once. C++ doesn't support Tail-call optimization though afaik, so too many recursive calls will lead to a StackOverflow exception. If you want to use recursion, you should be using a language that's setup to support its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method for the case when you want to search using by providing startIndex

```
 function large(int arr[], int startIndex, int length, int ans)
    {
        if (startIndex == length - 1)
            return ans;
         else
            return large(arr, startIndex+1, length, max(ans, arr[startIndex]);
    }

function max(a,b){
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be a solution. It is not **really** C++, but it is an implementation for a book exercise:

```
#include <iostream>

// LARGEST
// Returns the largest nuber in an array of int
// arr: the input array
// size: the length of our array (WARNING: segmentation fault if not correct)
int largest(int arr[], int size) {
  // Let's save the head of our vector
  int head = arr[0];

  // If we have reached the end of our vector we return the head
  // and the function does not continue
  if (size == 1)
    return head;

  // If we have still something in our array we go to check
  // the largest number in the tail
  int tail = largest(arr + 1, size - 1);

  // We return the biggest between the head and tail
  return (head > tail ? head : tail);
}

int main() {
  int arr[5] = {700,999,199,200,699};
  int max = largest(arr, 5);
  std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
```

If you also need a starting point different than 0, you may use this:

```
#include <iostream>

// LARGEST
// Returns the largest nuber in an array of int
// arr: the input array
// size: the length of our array (WARNING: segmentation fault if not correct)
// start: starting point for the search (default to 0)
int largest(int* arr, int size, int start = 0) {
  // Let's save the head of our vector, from the starting point
  int head = arr[start];

  int* _arr = arr + start; // Select the real new position of the 
  size -= start; // and decrementing the size accordingly

  // If we have reached the end of our vector we return the head
  // and the function does not continue
  if (size == 1)
    return head;

  // If we have still something in our array we go to check
  // the largest number in the tail
  int tail = largest(_arr + 1, size - 1);

  // We return the biggest between the head and tail
  return (head > tail ? head : tail);
}

int main() {
  int arr[5] = {700,999,199,200,699};
  int max = largest(arr, 5, 2);
  std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: arr[5] = {700,999,199,200,699}; if start=3 what will be the max value? can you please provide with index selection , so that it doesn't change OP's code intent

Comment: @MatteoRagni  I just want to ask something. If I use return in my code with function of Largest (where I am calling Largest), will this make my code recursive code ?

Comment: No, recursive means something else. The code I showed you is already recursive. Recursive revers to the fact that the function, in one of its instruction, calls itself. Prerequisites for a recursive function are: a recursive call (where the function calls itself but with different arguments) and an exit strategy (a situation in which the recursion is interrupted). Without an exit strategy the function continues to call itself infinitely (actually until reaching a stack too deep error). It is NOT a prerequisite to have return in front of a recursive call, but sometimes happens.

Answer (score 1):

It may work right, but this is not right way. Recursion method should be used carefully. See below

```
int large(int arr[], int size, int largest)
{
    if (size == 1)
        return largest;

    if (size > -1)
    {
        if (arr[size] > largest)
        {
            largest = arr[size];
        }
        return(largest = large(arr, size - 1, largest));
    }
    else
    {
        return largest;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: where is the answer?

Comment: Just added dear.

Comment: you shouldn't be using list  (c++ keyword) not a safe way to express keyword

Comment: User is using int start = 0, end = 4, max = 0;  user can select start ..but your solution takes size which is changing the intent of original code

Comment: arr[5] = {700,999,199,200,699};  if start=3 what will be the max value?

Comment: User is using start and end, but I think arr size easily accessible. We should provide good quality code. Otherwise, his/her function is already working for him/her as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Charu   Is this mean that when we call function recursively, we must call that function in return ?

Comment: @Student28 Yes, for this case.

Comment: @Charu Okay Thank you.